# Boot device not found on HP laptop after deleting partition

Tags: linux, windows

I have a problem because I deleted the fedora partition and probably accidentally the boot partition Windows 11. What should I do? When I open laptop this show me on screen: Boot Device Not Found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk. Hard Disk - (3F0).

Comment: Before anything else check UEFI settings > Boot menu and adjust accordingly (you probably want to select Windows bootloader manager). This assumes the dual-boot was installed in UEFI mode, of course.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: The EFI partition was probably deleted.

Comment: @harrymc My suspicion exactly. However, if I remember correctly, the standard automated Fedora installation also creates a separated `/boot` partition. Yes, users often confuse iot with the ESP, hence my suggestion "before anything else..."

Answer (score 0):

You have apparently destroyed the EFI boot partition, or the
BIOS boot would have found one or more of your two
operating systems.

You need a second computer to download and create a boot image of
the
[Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/).
This boot utility can recreate the boot environment and locate
your two operating systems. If successful, you will avoid the need
to reinstall everything.

Read well the documentation before using this utility.

If any data needs saving from the disk, do so as the first step.
You will need to create and boot a Linux Live USB for saving the data.